# Push Notifications Configuration Error - React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, push-notification

I am trying to create push notifications in my react native project both in iOS and android.

I have followed both the configuration instructions for react-native-push-notification and push-notification-ios, however when I run my app I get the following error.

[image: erorr]

After doing some online research I can't seem to find a fix for this problem.

Here is my code

```js
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";

const configure = () => {
 PushNotification.configure({

   onRegister: function(token) {
     //process token
   },

   onNotification: function(notification) {
     // process the notification
     // required on iOS only
     notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
   },

   permissions: {
     alert: true,
     badge: true,
     sound: true
   },

   popInitialNotification: true,
   requestPermissions: true,

 });
};

 export {
    configure,
   };
```